# How can I increase the max selected units in Starcraft single player?

Tags: starcraft

I've been playing Starcraft  again, and have found the most annoying thing about it is that I can only select a max of 12 units at a time. This is most annoying when playing as Zerg, as I often want to select all my drones, but often end up selecting my larvae as well.

Is there a way of increasing the max number of units you can have selected at a time in single player, either in game, by mod, tweaking a settings file, or another way?

Comment: as an option you could assign the packs of 12 units to a number. Like that you can quickly switch between the packs of 12

Comment: I agree with @Novarg that's the standard way control huge armies. here's a [vod of Boxer's keyboard (Brood War)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwQE4HuUUCA) and a [vod of DongRaeGu's keyboard (SC2)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=567bj3orRVs). But I wouldn't do it for larvae or drones (unless you know reavers are coming)

Comment: @BBz just a comment on the edit, i was meaning i often end up selecting my larvae by mistake when wanting to select all my drones to make them burrow

Comment: @GarethJones ah my bad - feel free to edit it to make that clear

Comment: I forget, can you double-click or control-click a unit to select all units of that type in SC1? Might help with selecting drones without including larvae.

Comment: @Wikwocket yes you can, but i find it hard to do so when im trying to defend my base from an attack, as often they are too fast for me . And i dont like having to change the speed constantly

Comment: @GarethJones what do you mean by "change the speed constantly" O_o

Comment: @bbz The game speed. Example time: Drones being attacked, I want to select them all and burrow them, however i cant drag select as ill select other units, namely larvae, and so miss selecting at least 3 drones and nor can i "click twice" as im trying deal with the attack rapidly (and the drones move too fast when trying to select). To respond in time, i have to change the game speed to slowest, select them all and tell them to burrow, then change the game speed back to fastest

Comment: @GarethJones hahaha that's pretty ingenious. practice ctrl-clicking; it does the same things as double-clicking but it's a faster way to select 12 of the same unit. it's true that the mechanics of BW are challenging, but improving at the game is part of the reward. i can only recommend steady practice. and maybe watch some first person vods of progamers, such as [Jaedong](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlphiHAI2hw)

Comment: This isn't a real solution, but it's something you might find useful: for air units, you can order one of them to patrol back and forth in your base, then order all future built air units to follow the patrolling unit (patrolling just lets you keep track of that one unit).  This way, you can move just that patrolling unit, and your entire armada will follow it.  The advantage is that it lets you swarm an enemy base very easily.  The downside is that, if that one unit dies, your units will resume their default behavior (spreading out a bit and killing everything).

Comment: Also, you can do the same trick with ground units, but it's much less effective because they'll bump into each other while following the patrol unit.

Comment: I think there's a better answer to the question now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

There is no legitimate (ethically acceptable) way of changing the game to select more than 12 units.

Mainly because mods in Brood War aren't like Minecraft mods, it doesn't just make the game more fun, it potentially (in this case, definitely) gives you an unfair advantage over your opponent.

As a long time Brood War player, I entreat you to avoid using these methods and enjoy the game's imperfect beauty.

---

But this may quench your thirst if you're not picky about experiencing the pure, true Brood War.

> [**Starcraft 2 - Brood War Remake**](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=145316)

[image]

Comment: While i understand the ethically acceptable for multiplier, i only want to do this for Singleplayer. From your answer i would guess that it can be done, just thats its disproved of. Would you be able to point me in the direction for finding "the way". Also I dont have SC2

Comment: @GarethJones I'm sorry, but I can't do that on Arqade. Although I can't stop people from seeking out hacks, I don't want to promote them as a solution either. I understand that people will have objections to my answer even alluding to unethical methods; but I don't think it's respectful to outright deceive people either. If you choose to change the basic mechanics of Brood War, I'm afraid you're missing out on the experience.

Comment: I too am only interested in StarCraft single player and have zero interest in multiplayer (and to be honest, I'd rather risk missing out on "enjoying the game's imperfect beauty" than succumb to frustration every time a unit gets left behind). However, your main point is that this would be unfair in multiplayer. Are you saying that mods for StarCraft aren't capable of being single player only?

Comment: @Atav32 I have downvoted this because it doesn't even attempt to answer the question. If your "ethics" (whatever that would mean in this context) don't allow you to mod the game that way, then don't answer to someone who wants to do just that. You're (the answers section) here to provide help, not to judge the way people choose to play their games. And I personally believe that "imperfect beauty" is a nonsense, especially given that SC2 removed that and a multitude of other quirks and made for a much more enjoyable experience.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz sounds good to me. thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there's a tool called [Oblivion](http://keops.fr.yuku.com/topic/255/BroodWar-Oblivion-v406f#.WW-WV4h97mE) that raises the limit to 255 units; should be enough given the supply limits.

It also introduces other sensible changes (like automatic mining), but I'm not sure if those can be enabled/disabled individually.

Comment: I, on the other hand, will upvote this because it does answer the question so well